# TrappedKeyDown doesn't work in my User Control

Tags: c#, user-controls

I would like to retrieve pressed Keys in my UserControl. 
The problem is that the keyboard notifications are posted to the control with the focus and this one is my windows form.

I already tried to focus the UserControl, but these approaches are not working.
For example:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
    if (keyData == Keys.Escape) {
        this.Visible = false;
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

has no effect.
Source: [UserControl KeyDown Event Not Fire Against Revoke Of Windows Application KeyDown Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308438/usercontrol-keydown-event-not-fire-against-revoke-of-windows-application-keydown)

If I initialize my UserControl the TrappedKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) Event is not firing.

Comment: Can you please try to reformulate your problem, 'cause I do'nt really know what's not working.

Comment: My UserControl is not able to retrieve the pressed Keys.

Comment: It works fine, there's something wrong with your UserControl.  Probably just the exact same thing your user will have a problem with, he can't tell that the UC has the focus so he has no idea what the Escape key is going to do.  Override OnEnter, OnLeave and have OnPaint call ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle().